# Move All Files from all Subfolders to Parent Folder using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, parent, subdirectory

How can someone move all files from all subfolders to parent folder using batch script. In the code below that I copied and pasted, shows how to do it but I have multiple parent folders that I need to do this in. I want to not have to edit the code for every time I have to do this.

Original

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\some dir\A"
set "dest=F:\other dir\B\"
for /r "%source%" %%d in (*) do move "%%d" "%dest%"
```

Rather it be something like this.

```
@echo off
set "source=(Current Parent Folder\All Subfolders)"
set "dest=(Current Parent Folder)"
for /r "%source%" %%d in (*) do move "%%d" "%dest%"
```

Edit: to add: The batch file is to be copied and pasted (or moved) into a new/different Parent Folder. Goal is to avoid having to edit the batch file every time it gets copied/moved.

Edit 2: It was supposed to be MOVE not Copy.

Comment: Wrap a `for /D` loop around the `for /R` loop: `for /D %%J in ("D:\Path\To\Root\*") do pushd "%%~J" && ((for /R %%I in (*.*) do copy "%%~I") & popd)`

Comment: @aschipfl I don't know how that keeps a person from still having to go in and edit the batch file each time it gets copied and pasted into a new Parent folder.

Comment: Well, you could replace `D:\Path\To\Root\*` by `%~dp0*` to use the parent directory of the batch file as the root…

Comment: @aschipfl Well I put this `for /D %%J in ("%~dp0*") do pushd "%%~J" && ((for /R %%I in (.) do move "%%~I") & popd)` and it "moved" (says it moved the files) files but not into the parent folder. In fact there doesn't seem to be any files moved at all. If they were moved/copied it doesn't tell me where they went. For all I know, there is now double files sitting in some unknow location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is using just one batch file stored in a directory of user´s choice and use a shortcut file in the `SendTo` folder to run the batch file for a folder of user´s choice by clicking with secondary (usually right) pointing device (mouse) button on a folder in *Windows File Explorer* to open the context menu and clicking with primary (usually left) pointing device button in submenu **Send to** on the menu item according to file name of the shortcut file.

### 1. Batch file for file movement

There can be created a batch file `%USERPROFILE%\MoveFilesToFolder.cmd` with the following single command line:

```
@if not "%~1" == "" for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~1\*" /AD-L /B /S 2^>nul') do @move "%%I\*" "%~1\"
```

The two `@` left to the commands `if` and `move` are just for avoiding the output of the parsed command lines before execution which is done in a multi-line batch file with `@echo off` at top of the batch file.

The **IF** condition evaluates to false if the batch file is started without passing an argument string to the batch file or with passing just `""` to the batch file (empty argument string) like on double clicking on the batch file itself. That condition makes sure not doing anything on batch file started without the required folder path as first argument string.

The `for /F` loop results in starting in background one more Windows command processor in addition to the `cmd.exe` process which is processing already the batch file with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` as additional arguments. So if the Windows is installed into `C:\Windows` and the batch file was started with `"C:\Temp\Development & Test(!)_100%"` as first argument string, there is executed in background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\Temp\Development & Test(!)_100%\*" /AD-L /B /S 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches

- in the specified directory `C:\Temp\Development & Test(!)_100%`
- only for directories including directories with hidden attribute with ignoring junctions and directory symbolic links because of option `/AD-L` (attribute directory and not a link)
- and all its subdirectories because of option `/S` and
- outputs all found directories matching the wildcard pattern `*` (any) in bare format because of option `/B` which means just folder name with full path because of option `/S` to handle **STDOUT** of the background command process.

It is possible that **DIR** fails to find any matching file system entry because of the specified directory does not have subdirectories at all or the batch file was started with passing a file name instead of a directory name to the batch file. In this case would be output to handle **STDERR** just an error message by **DIR** which is suppressed by redirecting the error message to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The Windows command processor instance processing the batch file captures all lines output to handle of **STDOUT** of background command process and waits for its self-termination before `for /F` is processing the captured output line by line with ignoring all empty lines.

There is by default split up each non-empty line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters, then is checked if the first space/tab delimited substring starts with a semicolon (default end of line character) in which case the line is ignored for further processing and otherwise just the first substring is assigned to the specified loop variable and then **FOR** runs the command(s) in its body.

The captured folder names with full path cannot contain a horizontal tab character and there cannot be a semicolon at beginning of the folder names with full path, but there can be one or more spaces in the fully qualified folder names. For that reason the option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters which results in each folder name is assigned completely to the specified loop variable `I`.

The command **MOVE** moves is run with the current folder name and moves nearly all files in that folder to the folder passed to the batch file with first argument string.

The command **MOVE** does not move files which

- have the hidden attribute set or
- are currently opened by an application with sharing access denied or
- exist already in the destination directory and the user denies overwriting of the file in the destination folder on prompt or
- exist already in the destination directory and the user confirms overwriting of the file in the destination folder, but the existing file in destination folder has the read-only attribute set.

The usage of the **MOVE** option `/Y` would avoid the prompt for the third case with file existing already in the destination folder. But the overwrite prompt appears even with using option `/Y` on existing file in destination folder with same name as a file in a subfolder has the read-only attribute set. It does not matter which option is chosen by the user on prompt as the read-only file in destination folder is nevertheless not replaced by the file in source folder.

The file movement is done which just updating the file allocation table of the file system of the drive. No file data is copied and deleted.

There could be used on Windows Vista and newer Windows client versions and on Windows Server 2003 and newer Windows server versions also:

```
@if not "%~1" == "" for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~1\*" /AD-L /B /S 2^>nul') do @%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%%I" "%~1" /MOV /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:1 /W:1 >nul
```

**ROBOCOPY** with the used options moves always all files including hidden files and read-only files independent on existing files in destination folder to the folder passed as argument string to the batch file also with just updating the file allocation table of the file system. But please note that the single command line solution using **ROBOCOPY** as posted here does not work on folder path ending with a backslash like on passing the root directory of a drive like `D:\` to the batch file. The backlash at end is in this case interpreted by **ROBOCOPY** as escape character for `"` marking end of destination path and **ROBOCOPY** interprets therefore all options up to `/W:1` as part of the destination path. The destination path with `"` and `:` would be interpreted as invalid by the file system and so no files are moved in this case. There would be additional code necessary in the batch file to handle also such a use case with passed folder path ending with a backslash on using **ROBOCOPY**.

### 2. Shortcut file for file movement

There is necessary next a shortcut file with file extension `.lnk` in the `SendTo` folder of the user account.

Such a shortcut file can be created by clicking with secondary pointing device button on the batch file `%USERPROFILE%\MoveFilesToFolder.cmd` and clicking with primary pointing device button in submenu **Send to** on the item **Desktop (create shortcut)**.

The user´s desktop has now a shortcut file with name `MoveFilesToFolder.cmd.lnk` whereby the file extension `.lnk` is not visible on desktop. There should be first clicked with secondary pointing device button on this shortcut and use from context menu **Rename** to change the file name, for example, to **Move files** which is later the name of the menu item in the **Send to** context submenu.

Then a secondary pointing device button click on the shortcut **Move files** is needed to open again the context menu and clicking this time on last menu item **Properties** to open the properties window for the shortcut file.

The property **Target** should be modified to:

```
 %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /E:ON /V:OFF /C "%USERPROFILE%\MoveFilesToFolder.cmd"
```

The property **Start in** should be cleared whereby the directory specified here does not really matter and could be also kept as is. It defines the current directory on execution of `cmd.exe` which is not important for the batch file which works independent on which directory is the current directory of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file. There could be used also `%SystemRoot%\System32` for **Start in** which is the directory containing `cmd.exe` for an even more fail-safe configuration.

The property **Run** can be configured with selecting *Minimized* to run `cmd.exe` for processing the batch file with a minimized window. Please note that when the minimized window does not disappear, the command **MOVE** prompts the user for overwriting a file. In this case the window must be restored and the prompt answered. There can be used in the batch file as second line also `@pause` on using the solution with command **MOVE** and use *Normal window* for **Run** in the shortcut file to always see the results of the file movements.

All other properties can be configured by the user according to personal preferences. The selection of a nice icon would be good and a good comment before clicking on button **OK**.

The shortcut file is now ready for being cut with <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> and pasted with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> into the folder opened by entering in address bar of *Windows File Explorer* the string `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` and hitting <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on Windows Vista and newer Windows client versions. The `SendTo` directory is on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 the directory `%USERPROFILE%\SendTo`.

### 3. How to use the shortcut and the batch file?

The user can now click with secondary pointing device button in *Windows File Explorer* on a folder and click in opened context menu in submenu **Send to** on the menu item **Move files**.

`explorer.exe` calls now the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to run `cmd.exe` with all the arguments specified with property **Target** in the shortcut file with appending to the end the fully qualified name of the clicked folder as additional argument. The property **Start in** in shortcut file defines the string of which function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` points to. Most of the other properties in the shortcut file determine other values passed via the [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure to function `CreateProcess`.

A user has a lot of control about how `cmd` is started for processing a batch file with the usage of a shortcut file which is the reason why I recommend using never directly a batch file on desktop, in Windows Start menu, or in special folders like `SendTo` or `Startup`.

It could happen that a user clicks with secondary pointing device button on a file and clicks by mistake on menu item **Move files** in the context submenu **Send to** instead of the menu item which should be really clicked. The batch file is designed to do nothing in this case caused by running the batch file by mistake with a fully qualified file name as argument string.